# Stucked in infinite loop (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, infinite-loop

I have 2 doc in firebase, posts and users, in posts table I have a uid, I am fetching "avatar" field from users doc with the help of uid in posts doc, see code:

```
     fetchAvatar(uid){
     var avatar;
     this.$db.collection("users")
         .doc(uid)
         .get().then(snapshot => {
         avatar = snapshot.data().avatar
     });
     return avatar;
 }

 <q-list
   class="rounded-borders q-mt-md q-mb-md"
   v-for="(post, key) in posts"
   :key="post.key"
  >
   <div v-if="key == 0" v-scroll-fire="(new_group = false)"></div>
   <PostDisplay
    :key="key"
    :type="post.type"
    :avatar="fetchAvatar(post.uid)" // Calling function there
    :more="post.more"
    :name="post.owner"
    :group="post.group_name"
    :timestamp="post.created_at"
    :likeCount="post.likes.length"
    :commentCount="post.comments.length"
    :comments="post.comments"
    :text="post.text"
    doc="posts"
    :id="post.id"
    class="dropshadow"
    :media-urls="post.mediaUrls"
    :post="post"
   />
  </q-list>
```

[Infinite loop error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTAh9.png)

I need a proper resolution for this error, I really appreciate the one who give me the right answer.

Comment: this error comes when you have same keys in a  loop. so for that just use different keys inside loop

Comment: I edit post.key to post.uid but this is not the key problem, I searched and read many blog/web/post that if the data in loop is changed Vue.js re-render the loop, so I am looking a way to get avatar for each post by post.uid, do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

`key="post.key"` looks really suspicious. I doubt the posts have a key property. You should really use `post.id` as a key.
Defining a `key` on `PostDisplay` is useless because you already define one on parent.
Also `(post, index)` instead of `(post, key)` would help to avoid mixing concepts up.

Side-notes :

- Passing individual properties (type, more, owner, ...) to PostDisplay is ok. Passing the whole `post` is also ok. But doing both at the same time is weird.
- More problematic, I see you pass the whole `posts` array on each PostDisplay. You should really make PostDisplay emit events and let its parent act on posts array.

*Edit:*
Anyway, to find what's the issue you can remove some parts of your code until it starts functioning again. Try to remove the div with v-scroll-fire. Then try to remove the avatar attribute.

That being said your fetchAvatar is wrong. It will always return undefined because $db call being asynchronous, `avatar = ...` will always be evaluated after the function fetchAvatar as returned it's (undefined) value.
What I'd probably do:

```
// :avatar="fetchAvatar(post.uid)"
fetchAvatar(uid) {
  return () => this.$db.collection("users")
         .doc(uid)
         .get().then(snapshot => snapshot.data().avatar)
}
```

and on PostDisplay.vue:

```
data() { return { fetchedAvatar: '' } },
created() { // or mounted()
  this.avatar().then(avatar => { this.fetchedAvatar = avatar })
}
```

Comment: I edit post.key to post.uid but this is not the key problem, I searched and read many blog/web/post that if the data in loop is changed Vue.js re-render the loop, so I am looking a way to get avatar for each post by post.uid, do you have any solution for that?

Comment: Using post.uid as a key is not better because I guess the same user can make several posts. `:key="key"` is still the safest if you have no unique id on posts. I edited my answer regarding other possible issues.

Comment: your solution didn't work, dear you didn't understand the problem, the problem is that as I said when I fetch data using post.uid inside v-for loop when vue see any change in v-for loop it re-render the loop cycle, hence it is creating infinite loop.

Comment: Seriously, you're not even giving feedback about the solution I provided (the fetchAvatar alternative and letting PostDisplay starting the fetch from hook). How do you want we progress?

Comment: I told you that your solution is not working, I want to fetch avatar inside loop by using post.uid.